# `replaceState` replaces URL on the address bar but Angular digest cycle sets back the url to the initial one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, browser

`replaceState` replaces URL on the address bar of the browser but when angularjs digest cycle run, it updates the URL back with the old one.

So, if:
1) Initially the URL was : `www.example.com/example`

2) After `replaceState`, it becomes `www.example.com/route/1`
`$window.history.replaceState('Object', document.title, "/route/" + $scope.routeParams1);`

3) When user clicks a button having `ng-click` or digest cycle runs, then the URL changes back to intial URL : `www.example.com/example`

How can we prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly? You just want to change the url without changing the actual content? Otherwise you should use ui-sref e.g, when using angular-ui-router.

Comment: @ZdenekHatak, Yes, I just want to change URL without changing or loading the page.